# Outlook not loading unless I enter noextensions or safe:3 switches

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010

My Outlook 2010 Pro now starts only when I enter the noextensions or safe:3 switches. Any ideas on what to do to fix this (except for running repair with a CD)?

Comment: Uninstall any extensions you have then try.  If that doens't work then repairing the installation is your only choice.

Comment: @Ramhound how can I tell which extensions I have on Outlook?

Comment: Just view them in the Options->Add-ins menu: http://i.stack.imgur.com/imUHz.png

Answer (score 0):

Run command one-by-one and reboot:

`Outlook /cleanfreebusy`

`Outlook /cleanreminders`

`Outlook /cleanfinders`

`Outlook /resetnavpane`

may be help ...